# Power BI Subtract Hours from a Timestamp

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I am trying to get a time for when the report was last refreshed in Power BI.

I have created this in M:

```
#table(type table[Date Last Refreshed=datetime], {{DateTime.LocalNow()}})
```

How can I subtract 6 hours from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
= #table(type table[Date Last Refreshed=datetime], {{DateTime.LocalNow()-#duration(0, 6, 0, 0)}})
```